# Spread syntax for Map in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, object-literal

In my React project (Chat App), I am using `redux toolkit`, I want to use `Map` in place of `object literal {}` as state.

`chatMap state` contains contactId (`mongodb _id`) as key and chat array as value.

something like that  -

```
chatMap =
{
   [contactId1]: [chatsArr1],
   [contactId2]: [chatsArr2]
}
```

**(chatSlice.js)**

```
const initialState = {
   chatMap: new Map(),
   ...
}
```

```
reducers: {
      setChatMap: (state, action) => {
         state.chatMap = {...chatMap, key1: action.payload}
      },
      ...
}
```

How to update chatMap (Map) state ?

Comment: Please note that we generally recommend against storing class instances like Maps in a Redux store - see the style guide on this: https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#do-not-put-non-serializable-values-in-state-or-actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you're looking for:

```
reducers: {
      setChatMap: (state, action) => {
         state.chatMap = new Map([...chatMap, [key1, action.payload]]) 
      },
      ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```js
reducers: {
      setChatMap: (state, action) => {
         state.chatMap = new Map(state.chatMap).set('key1', action.payload)
      },
      ...
}
```

Comment: I can only accept one answer.

Answer (score 0):

Firt you can convert the map to an object, then spread it. Again convert the final object to a map.

```js
reducers: {
      setChatMap: (state, action) => {
         const obj = object.fromEntries(chatMap);
         const tCM = {...obj, key1: action.payload};
         state.chatMap = new Map(tCM);
      },
      ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem relies on the fact that, React has now way of knowing if your object(Map) has changed or not, since its a bit more complicated than a primitive, you need to make what's called a [deep-copy](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-shallow-and-deep-copy-of-a-class/) of that object.

By passing a new object, react will see a new [reference](https://javascript.info/object-copy) and then trigger a new render.

Cheers

Comment: thanks for helpful reference link mentioned in answer.